# Problems with Azure's MobileService component

Tags: mono, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

We’ve been experiencing strange problems with the WindowsAzure.Mobile component. It keeps giving a strange exception when retrieving data from the server which it never did before. The project where we use that component also uses it to login with Google & Facebook and that also has been throwing weird exception. This behavior started showing up after updating Xamarin.Studio to the new version.

**WindowsAzure.Mobile Authentication error:**

[image]

**WindowsAzure.Mobile Get error:**

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. at System.DateTime.op_Subtraction (DateTime d, TimeSpan t) [0x00000] in :0 at Android.Runtime.AndroidCurrentSystemTimeZone.IsAmbiguousTime (DateTime time) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/62e09eb0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/AndroidCurrentSystemTimeZone.cs:113 at Android.Runtime.AndroidCurrentSystemTimeZone.GetUtcOffset (DateTime time) [0x00049] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/62e09eb0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/AndroidCurrentSystemTimeZone.cs:100 at System.TimeZone.ToLocalTime (DateTime time) [0x00000] in :0 at System.DateTime.ToLocalTime () [0x00000] in :0 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceIsoDateTimeConverter.ReadJson (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in :0 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter converter, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Object existingValue) [0x00000] in :0 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x00000] in :0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in :0 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1[System.Collections.Generic.List1[Dvit.Apps.OpenBiz.Pcl.Models.SysType]].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 at Dvit.Apps.OpenBiz.Pcl.Services.AzureService+d__35`1[Dvit.Apps.OpenBiz.Pcl.Models.SysType].MoveNext () [0x0006a] in c:\Code\Dvit\Dvit.Apps.Bizzumi.Android\Main\Source\Dvit.Apps.OpenBiz.Pcl\Services\AzureService.cs:390

**Has anybody been experiencing the same type of problems? We have not found any solution yet.**

Comment: This seems to be related to this https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=22700

Comment: It looks like the same issue. I'll keep a eye on this thread, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug when working with CEST (Central European Summer Time) as timezone. If i switch the timezone from the device i debug on to something else than CEST, it will not crash anymore. We opened a thread on bugzilla, for the people who want to follow: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22955